# What memoization libraries are available for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, memoization

There are many Javascript libraries out there for memoizing functions.

What are some of the best ones (high quality, flexible, fast, etc.), for the various use-cases?

Answer (score 15):

I've found that there are **tons** of different JavaScript memoization libraries out there, and they all operate in slightly different ways.

I'll attempt to list and compare the "best" ones here. (ordered roughly by how effective/general-purpose I estimate them to be; or rather, that's the plan once I have time to look them over further!)

**Core features**: (marked with ✔️yes, ❌no, ⚙️partial, ❔unknown)

> **npm) Install from NPM:** The package is available on npm. (for easy integration/updating)
> **m-arg) Multiple arguments:** Can memoize functions that are passed multiple arguments.
> **o-arg) Object arguments:** Can memoize functions that are passed object arguments.
> **o-hash) Object hashing:** Can memoize using the internal JS hashing for `object` arguments, through use of `Map`/`WeakMap`. (better perf than serialization or cache-entry iteration)
> **m-slot) Multiple slots:** Can store cached results for more than just the last set of arguments. (without requiring manual creation of new "cache slots" / "instantiations")
> **auto) Auto-memoize:** Can memoize based on the regular passed arguments; does not require *function-specific* setup/wrapping for basic memoization. (may still require a generic wrapping)

### For synchronous functions

#### [moize](https://github.com/planttheidea/moize) (based on [micro-memoize](https://github.com/planttheidea/micro-memoize))

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moize): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ❌, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️
> Popularity) GitHub stars: ~550; NPM weekly downloads: ~76k (2020-04-24)

#### [memoizee](https://github.com/medikoo/memoizee)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ⚙️, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️
> Popularity) GitHub stars: ~1.1k; NPM weekly downloads: ~1.9m (2020-04-24)

#### [mobx-utils:computedFn](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#computedfn)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx-utils): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ✔️, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️
> Popularity) GitHub stars: ~850; NPM weekly downloads: ~60k (2020-04-24)

#### [fast-memoize](https://github.com/caiogondim/fast-memoize.js)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-memoize): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ❌, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️
> Popularity) GitHub stars: ~2.2k; NPM weekly downloads: ~381k (2020-04-24)

#### [map-memo](https://github.com/StarryInternet/map-memo)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@starryinternet/map-memo): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ✔️, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️

#### [lodash.memoize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#memoize) ([code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/memoize.js))

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.memoize): ✔️, m-arg: ❌, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ✔️, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️

#### [memoize-weak](https://github.com/timkendrick/memoize-weak)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-weak): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ✔️, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️

#### [memoize-immutable](https://github.com/memoize-immutable/memoize-immutable)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-immutable): ✔️, m-arg: ✔️, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ✔️, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️

#### [underscore.memoize](https://underscorejs.org/#memoize) ([code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js))

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore): ✔️, m-arg: ❌, o-arg: ✔️, o-hash: ❌, m-slot: ✔️, auto: ✔️

#### [memoize-state](https://github.com/theKashey/memoize-state)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [kashe](https://github.com/theKashey/kashe)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [nano-memoize](https://github.com/anywhichway/nano-memoize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoizerific](https://github.com/thinkloop/memoizerific)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoize-fn](https://github.com/imcuttle/memoize-fn)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoize-cache](https://github.com/sithmel/memoize-cache)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoize-one](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one)

> Core features) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-one): ✔️, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❌, auto: ❔

#### [use-memo-one](https://github.com/alexreardon/use-memo-one)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❌, auto: ❔

#### [@emotion/weak-memoize](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/weak-memoize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [lru-memoizer](https://github.com/jfromaniello/lru-memoizer)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [mem](https://github.com/sindresorhus/mem)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoizejs](https://github.com/addyosmani/memoize.js)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memize](https://github.com/aduth/memize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❌

#### [rememo](https://github.com/aduth/rememo)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❌

#### [memoize-bind](https://github.com/timkendrick/memoize-bind)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoizesync](https://github.com/papandreou/node-memoizesync)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [@thi.ng/memoize](https://github.com/thi-ng/umbrella/tree/develop/packages/memoize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [trie-memoize](https://github.com/jaredLunde/trie-memoize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memobind](https://github.com/supnate/memobind)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoize-id](https://github.com/elliottsj/memoize-id)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [@bigcommerce/memoize](https://github.com/bigcommerce/memoize-js)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

### For asynchronous functions

#### [mobx-utils:computedFn](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#computedfn)

> [see entry above in synchronous category]

#### [p-memoize](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-memoize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [node-memoizeasync](https://github.com/papandreou/node-memoizeasync)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [promise-memoize](https://github.com/nodeca/promise-memoize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [use-async-memo](https://github.com/awmleer/use-async-memo)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [async-memo-ize](https://github.com/aboutlo/async-memo-ize)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

#### [memoize-async](https://github.com/azer/memoize-async)

> Core features) npm: ❔, m-arg: ❔, o-arg: ❔, o-hash: ❔, m-slot: ❔, auto: ❔

### Discussion

There are actually many more JS memoization libraries than this (I know...), but I've left out ones where the library:

- Cannot memoize in-memory. (eg. file-based cache only)
- Cannot memoize standalone functions. (eg. class methods only)
- Is not open-source, or hosted at some crazy place [like this](https://git.scuttlebot.io/%25K9F59ErM3SGEzAY%2FO%2BJj1z6LT%2FvnvcvDQkeo%2Bbrvoys%3D.sha256) XD.
- Was beyond the first few pages of results. (one can only invest so much time into this...)

Comment: Asked and answered in the very same minute...

Comment: @Eldar You're supposed to do that when you can't find a good answer, and the existing questions are not a good enough match for your query: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Venryx One important thing which you didn't mention in your review is proper Promise handling. It is important not to remember async errors, happened due to, for instance, transport problem. Other important criteria are speed, configurable cache.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know by which criteria you ordered your list. And, probably some conclusion... And one more thing: IMHO projects which updated more than a year ago shouldn't be taken into account.

Comment: I agree there are a number of other criteria that would be nice to include, but I lost motivation to work on it further once moderators closed the question. As for how I ordered the entries: it was supposed to be roughly by what percentage of developers' use-cases would be suitably covered by the library (ie. the probability that the library would work well for one's case, without knowing your specific requirements). Of course, this ordering is not really meaningful until the features of all the entries are evaluated. (which, as mentioned, was not completed due to loss of motivation)