# Memoize function with all types of arguments support

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, memoization

Is there any way we can create a very generic function that supports all arguments?

```
function memoize(expensivefn) {
  const map = new Map();

  // args can have array, object, functions and any other data types
  return function(...args) {
    if (map.has(args)) return map.get(args);

    const result = expensivefn(...args);

    map.set(args, result);
    return result;
  };
}

const expensiveFunction = args => {
  console.log("A very expensive function, can block the tread!");
};

const memfun = memoize(expensiveFunction);

// calling function with named function
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
memfun(add); // invoke the expensive function

memfun(add); // return from cache


// calling function with anonymous function
memfun(() => {
  console.log("print someting!");
}); // invoke the expensive function

memfun(() => {
  console.log("print someting!");
}); // return from cache


// Calling function with array and object

memfun([1, 2, 4, 4], { name: "abc" }); // invoke the expensive function

memfun([1, 2, 4, 4], { name: "abc" }); // return from cache
```

Comment: Could you explain what the expected result is?

Comment: Using objects as keys in a `Map` compares their identity, not their contents. `args` is a *new* array in each call.

Comment: @MaartenDev I have added comments to every line, the result can be anything, it just has to work as a very generic memorize function.

Comment: @Bergi yes you're right, so is there any other data structure or anything that can achieve the same goal?

Comment: You could look at existing solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402805/6310593

Comment: @MaartenDev Thanks for suggesting libraries. but can we make it simple and write the solution here, So, others can also see the code instead of diving into endless libraries.