# Javascript sorting function incorrectly changes elements' position in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm using an array sorting function with my AngularJS app. It uses a variable, `direction`, to determine whether to sort the data in an ascending (`direction === -1`) or descending (`direction === 1`) manner.

**What's going wrong**: Sometimes when I do a sort, elements in the array which should be in the same position are returned in a different position, without anything in the array actually changing.

For instance, if I have:

```
   var arr = [
       {id: 3, name: 'd'},
       {id: 2, name: 'b'},
       {id: 1, name: 'a'},
       {id: 2, name: 'c'}
   ];
```

and I sort it by "id" with a direction of `-1`, it will return with names as "a,b,c,d" as you'd expect. Then I'll sort again (changing the direction to `1`) and it will reverse the direction. But then if I sort it again (with `direction === -1`), it will return with an order of "a,c,b,d".

This is a simplified example; in reality it's far less predictable than this.

I have a feeling I'm not using the `direction` properly in my sort. See below:

```
this.sortData = function (data, type, direction) {

    return data.sort(sortFunct);

    function sortFunct(a, b) {
        var numberTypes = ['Thread', 'Job', 'FolderCount', 'MessageCount', 'EmailCount', 'CalendarCount', 'TaskCount', 'OtherCount', 'JobId', 'BatchId', 'ItemsTotal', 'ItemsRemaining', 'ItemsFailed', 'Size', 'progress', 'PercentComplete'];
        var stringTypes = ['Level', 'StatusMessage', 'Author', 'ItemStatus', 'JobStatus', 'SourceMailbox', 'TargetMailbox', 'Subject', 'Folder', 'MessageClass', 'StatusMessage', 'Path', 'Owner1',];

        if (numberTypes.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
            return direction * (a[type] - b[type]);
        } else if (stringTypes.indexOf(type) !== -1) {
            if (!a[type]) {
                return 1;
            } else if (!b[type]) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return a[type].localeCompare(b[type]) * direction;
            }
        } else if (type === 'DiscoveryDate' || type === 'ReceivedDate' || type === 'Timestamp') {
            if (a[type] > b[type]) {
                return direction * 1;
            } else if (a[type] < b[type]) {
                return direction * -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return direction * (a[type] - b[type]);
        }
    } // End sortFunct
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ECMAScript spec for `.sort()` does not require it to be stable, thus elements that your custom sort function says are the same (e.g. returns `0`) will be in no guaranteed order with respect to each other and, in fact, the order they end up in may be influenced by the order they were in before the sort.

If you want a consistent sort, then you need to never return `0` from your custom sort function unless the two items are completely identical such that you could never tell which was which.

When the primary key is the same, you need to then test a secondary key and return the result of that comparison.  If the secondary key is the same, then compare a tertiary key and so on as far as it is worth it to you to go.

This secondary comparison can make the sort stable so that it will always land in a predictable order, no matter what order you had it in before.

---

I've also seen sort schemes that create a unique key and assign it to every object and use that as the secondary or tertiary key, thus guaranteeing that if the keys you care about are the same, you can then compare the unique key and always have a consistent stable sort.

---

Here's an example of a scheme that preserves the original order if the comparison field (age in this case has the same value).  To know what the original order was, it tags each object with an `origOrder` property that identifies the original order.

```js
var data = [
  {name: "Amy", age: 13},
  {name: "Anne", age: 13},
  {name: "John", age: 11},
  {name: "Jack", age: 12},
  {name: "Ted", age: 11},
  {name: "Alice", age: 12}
];
  
// mark each object with the original order  
data.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.origOrder = index;
});  
  
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var diff = a.age - b.age;
  if (diff !== 0) {
    return diff;
  } else {
    return a.origOrder - b.origOrder;
  }
});  

// show results in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Using a Map object from ES6, we could also do this without touching the original objects in the array by creating a temporary index that we used for resolving ties and storing that in the Map object.  That could work like this:

```js
    var data = [
      {name: "Amy", age: 13},
      {name: "Anne", age: 13},
      {name: "John", age: 11},
      {name: "Jack", age: 12},
      {name: "Ted", age: 11},
      {name: "Alice", age: 12}
    ];
    
    // put each object in a temporary map with its original index
    let tempMap = new Map();
    data.forEach((item, index) => {
        tempMap.set(item, index);
    });
      
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      var diff = a.age - b.age;
      if (diff !== 0) {
        return diff;
      } else {
        return tempMap.get(a) - tempMap.get(b);
      }
    });  

    // show results in snippet
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You can see, by looking at the sorted results, that the relative order of two entries with the same age is retained without modifying the original objects in any way.

Comment: Asked this in comments of another answer, but is it possible to return `a` and `b`s index within the original array through the sort function, comparing that and returning `-1` or `1` as a secondary comparison?

Comment: @Jascination - `.sort()` does not provide the original index to the callback.  The last paragraph of my answer that discusses adding a unique key to each object being sorted in an array of objects provides that capability if you simply make the unique key be ascending and then use it as the final arbiter for ties.  That will preserve the original order for sort keys of the same value.

Comment: well if `data = data.sort(sortFunction)`, couldn't I just do `if(data.indexOf(a) > data.indexOf(b)` within that `sortFunction` instead of doing an extra loop? Trying to think of performance here (although I just tried this and nothing is different so I'm likely wrong)

Comment: @Jascination - You're assuming a bunch of things that aren't true like there are no dups in the array, that the element has not already been moved, etc...  Remember, `.sort()` sorts the original array in place so elements get moved around during the sort.  The original position is quickly lost unless it is recorded somehow in another data structure before sorting.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, didn't realise that the data would be moved around during the sort itself! Doing a separate loop is probably best. Cheers for your help.

Comment: Added an ES6 way of doing this that does not modify the original array of objects in any way.

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript does not require the sort to be stable ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers)). Also, even if the sort is stable, you can't expect the code to know when identical records (2 and 2) should be reversed and when not. In order to be able to do this, you cannot afford to ever return `0` from the comparator - i.e. in case of a tie, you need a secondary key that will help disambiguate the order. If you can't think of anything better, you can give each object [a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020670/javascript-object-id).

Comment: Interesting, didn't know the right terminology to be searching for here. Would you say that returning the original index of `a` and `b` and then comparing with that via a secondary key would make the sort more stable?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "returning the original index" - returning from where? What I mean is, having a field that is truly unique is a big thing; if that's the unmodified array index, that's fine, but it would have to be put onto the object beforehand so that the comparator can access it.

Comment: I do have an ID field that is unique, but I don't see how comparing on that would affect stability in sorting an array. What I meant was the original index of the element within the array; if the comparison would === 0, and a's original index in the array is lower than b's, return 1, else -1.

Answer (score 1):

"The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The sort is **not** necessarily **stable**."

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

And also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

'HTH,