# Create a unique object identifier with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

The objects I use on the client side need a unique ID. My array of objects is very small, commonly 4 items, not more.

I use this:

```
export class MyItem {   
    uniqueObjectIdentifier: number;
    constructor(obj) {    
        this.uniqueObjectIdentifier = Math.random();
    }
}
```

Is there something maybe javascript or angular internal that I can access instead of the handcrafted property?

Comment: Not flagging because I don't know enough about `angular`, `typescript`, or `ecmascript-6`, but is this the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1997661/1586231)?

Comment: What is wrong with `Math.random()` ?

Comment: `Math.random()` is not unique. In javascript it's actually pseudo random, so it will repeat itself eventually.

Comment: What do you  want to use the id for? Why do you think you need them? Every object already has an identity that distinguishes it from others.

Comment: Here I reas as solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020670/javascript-object-id that javascript has no built in identifier. I created objects on client side for a data grid. The one object currently edited shows the edit template for this I need the unique id :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

> Every symbol value returned from Symbol() is unique.

```
export class MyItem {
  uniqueObjectIdentifier: symbol;
  constructor(obj) {
    this.uniqueObjectIdentifier = Symbol();
  }
}
```

If browser support doesn't allow you to use a symbol, you can use a reference to an object instead.

```
export class MyItem {
  uniqueObjectIdentifier: object;
  constructor(obj) {
    this.uniqueObjectIdentifier = {};
  }
}
```

Comment: Wondering how is `Symbol()` or `{}` different from the actual `var item1 = new MyItem(); item2 = new MyItem()`

Comment: as you asked before bhantol, nothing wrong with Math.random(). Just curious how a decade later... such stuff is handled :-)

Comment: >  A symbol value may be used as an identifier for object properties. There are built in special symbols, such as iterator. In addition, the purpose of a symbol is to be a unique identifier. The purpose of an object is to be an object. In this regard, there's not difference between `{}` and `new MyItem()`.

Comment: @bhantol A `Symbol` is `Object` like, yet much simpler than a real `Object`. For instance, you can't assign a custom property to a `Symbol`. So it probably requires less memory.

Comment: Very nice `Symbol`. Hope IE soon starts supporting.

Comment: and Math.random() purpose is a random number, not to be unique ;-)

Comment: Why is browser support a problem at all? This can be fixed with Symbol polyfill, and polyfills are first class citizens in every web project.

Comment: Not a big problem. I like poly fills rather than clutter my code. Already liking Symbol

Answer (score 2):

In **TypeScript** you can do this:

```
export class MyItem {
  static currentId: number = 0;
  uniqueObjectIdentifier: number;

  constructor(obj) {
    this.uniqueObjectIdentifier = MyItem.currentId++;
  }
}
```

In **JavaScript** ES6:

```
export class MyItem {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.uniqueObjectIdentifier = MyItem.currentId++;
  }
}
MyItem.currentId = 0;
```

Or you can use unexported, module scoped variable to hold the counter:

```
let currentId = 0;

export class MyItem {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.uniqueObjectIdentifier = currentId++;
  }
}
```

That way `currentId` can't be modified from outside the module.