# comparing javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like a function that compares to arrays of javascript strings, and saving the values that didnt match in to a new array. At the moment im using a nested jquery foreach. But i think there are better ways than this?

```
$.each(imagesInUploadsFolder, function(i, outervalue){
            $.each(imagesInDatabaseTable, function(i, innervalue){

                if(outervalue == innervalue){
                    //match in both arrays...
                } 

            });
        });
```

Comment: You obviously want to use the `===` operator for the comparison...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using a JSON object and no jQuery, although the `$.inArray()` should work fine:

```
var imagesInUploadsFolder = [
    '/path/to/img1.png',
    '/path/to/img2.png',
    '/path/to/img3.png'
];
var imagesInDatabaseTable = [
    '/path/to/img1.jpg',
    '/path/to/img2.png',
    '/path/to/img4.png'
];

var database_json = JSON.stringify(imagesInDatabaseTable);

for (var i = 0; i < imagesInUploadsFolder.length; i++) {
    console.log(imagesInUploadsFolder[i] + ' in ' + database_json);
    if (database_json.indexOf(imagesInUploadsFolder[i]) > -1) {
        console.log('In database: ' + imagesInUploadsFolder[i]);
    } else {
        console.log('Not in database: ' + imagesInUploadsFolder[i]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nJPW/1/

**EDIT**

Actually, the JSON method isn't needed (?):

```
for (var i = 0; i < imagesInUploadsFolder.length; i++) {
    console.log(imagesInUploadsFolder[i] + ' in ' + imagesInDatabaseTable);
    if (imagesInDatabaseTable.indexOf(imagesInUploadsFolder[i]) > -1) {
        console.log('In database: ' + imagesInUploadsFolder[i]);
    } else {
        console.log('Not in database: ' + imagesInUploadsFolder[i]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nJPW/2/

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention that i was looking for the missmatches only. A little bit modified :) http://jsfiddle.net/7nJPW/1/

Comment: @Johan - You can drop the `JSON` part, it's unnecessary. See my edit.

Comment: @Johan - And this will be better (see the `c_uploads`): http://jsfiddle.net/7nJPW/4/

Comment: @Johan - Note that `indexOf()` on arrays is a newer method, and some older browsers may not support it natively (or, for that matter, `JSON.stringify()`. See: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: @Johan See my post for a relevant example and implementation of a function that does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: My last comment with jsfiddle didnt contain my update, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7nJPW/6/ . Regarding the old browsers; I think its only IE7 that has some issues with that.

Comment: @Johan - If you use the [es5 shim library](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), it should work there too, if you need it to.

Comment: Its ok, thanks anyway. And thank you for your detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
arr1.forEach( function ( elem ) {
    if ( arr2.indexOf( elem ) > -1 ) {
        // match...
    }
});
```

where `arr1` and `arr2` are your two arrays...

(Btw, ES5 shim for IE8, of course...)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes? What is it?

Comment: +1, but you'll have to shim both forEach **and** indexOf, won't you?

Comment: I was surprised that `indexOf()` would work on an `array`. That's all.

Comment: @Adam Yes, if you care about IE8, you have to include ES5-shim... (which is not me btw, hehe... )

Answer (score 1):

It is the most easier way i can think of right now :)

```
 $.each(imagesInUploadsFolder, function(i, outervalue){
       if($.inArray(imagesInDatabaseTable,outervalue)>-1){
               //my operation
       }
    }
```

FYI: Actually inArray returns index of innermatch else -1. Just incase you need it.

Comment: Why use jQuery, when `.forEach()` and `.indexOf()` get the job done... `:)`

Comment: he is already using jquery so why not write everything in jquery style  .. :)

Comment: And i dont think that this is memory consuming part of his code :)

Comment: Not the memory consumption, but the performance (= how fast it executes...)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use foreach of pure javascript?

```
for (var i = 0; i < innervalue.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < outervalue.length; j++){
        if (innervalue[i] === outervalue[j])
           // match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use jQuery or `for` loops, straight-out comparison will be O(n<sup>2</sup>), since you'll need to compare each element of one array with every element of another array.

If the objects are comparable, you can sort the items using a suitable comparison function, then loop over the two arrays simultaneously, examining if one element is less than the other. If you're familiar with merge-sort, this is very similar to the merge step. Assuming the comparison function is O(1), sorting is O(n*log(n)), and the merge-like comparison loop is O(n), the total time complexity is O(n*log(n)), where "n" is the length of the larger array.

```
    imagesInUploadsFolder.sort(imgCmp);
    imagesInDatabaseTable.sort(imgCmp);
    // diff will hold the difference of the arrays
    var diff = [];
    var i=0, j=0, cmp;
    while (i < imagesInUploadsFolder.length && j < imagesInDatabaseTable.length) {
        cmp = cmp(imagesInUploadsFolder[i], imagesInDatabaseTable[j]);
        if (cmp < 0) {
            // up[i] < db[j]
            ++i;
            diff.append(imagesInUploadsFolder[i]);
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            // up[i] > db[j]
            ++j;
            diff.append(imagesInDatabaseTable[j]);
        } else {
            // up[i] == db[j]
            ++i; ++j;
        }
    }
    // one of the arrays may still have items; if so, loop over it and add the items
    if (i < imagesInUploadsFolder.length) {
        for (; i < imagesInUploadsFolder.length; ++i) {
            diff.append(imagesInUploadsFolder[i]);
        }
    } else if (j < imagesInDatabaseTable.length)) {
        for (; i < imagesInDatabaseTable.length; ++i) {
            diff.append(imagesInDatabaseTable[i]);
        }
    }
    // diff now holds items that are in only one of the two arrays.
```

If you can define a suitable [object ID function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997661/), you can create an ancillary data structure that holds a set of elements. If accessing object properties is O(f(n)) (for hashes, f ≈ 1; for balanced trees, f = log(n)), then this approach is O(n*f(n)), so it should have no worse complexity than the sort-and-compare approach. Untested and inefficient implementation:

```
function Set(from) {
    this.elements = {};
    this.size = 0;
    if (from) {
        for (var i=0; i < from.length) {
            this.add(from[i]);
        }
    }
}
Set.prototype.each = function(f) {
    var eltId;
    foreach (eltId in this.elements) {
        f(this.elements[eltId], eltId);
    }
};
Set.prototype.clone = function() {
    var clone = new Set();
    this.each(function(obj, id) {
        clone.add(obj);
    });
    return clone;
};
Set.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    return obj.uniqueId() in this.elements;
};
Set.prototype.add = function(obj) {
    var objId = obj.uniqueId();
    if (! (objId in this.elements)) {
        ++this.size;
        this.elements[objId] = obj;
    }
    return this;
};
Set.prototype.remove = function(obj) {
    var objId = obj.uniqueId();
    if (objId in this.elements) {
        --this.size;
        delete this.elements[objId];
    }
    return this;
};
Set.prototype.union = function(other) {
    other.each(function(elt, id) { this.add(elt); });
    return this;
};
Set.prototype.sub = function(other) {
    other.each(function (elt, id) {
        this.remove(elt);
    });
    return this;
};
Set.prototype.diff = function(other) {
    var mine = this.clone();
    mine.sub(other);
    var others = other.clone();
    others.sub(this);
    mine.union(others);
    return mine;
};
Set.prototype.toArray = function(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    this.each(function(elt, id) {
        arr.append(elt);
    });
    return arr;
};

var uploadsSet = new Set(imagesInUploadsFolder),
    dbSet = new Set(imagesInDatabaseTable),
    imagesInJustOne = uploadsSet.diff(dbSet);
```

If you want both the union and difference of the arrays, you can define a suitable method on `Set` to more efficiently calculate them instead of using `Set.diff` and `Set.union` separately.