# Check if every element in one array is in a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two arrays and I want to check if every element in `arr2` is in `arr1`. If the value of an element is repeated in `arr2`, it needs to be in `arr1` an equal number of times. What's the best way of doing this?

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [1, 2]

checkSuperbag(arr1, arr2)
> true //both 1 and 2 are in arr1

arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [1, 2, 5]

checkSuperbag(arr1, arr2)
> false //5 is not in arr1

arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 3]

checkSuperbag(arr1, arr2)
> false //3 is not in arr1 twice
```

Comment: The last example should be returning false. If the 2 arrays have the same length, there is no super/subset. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superset.html

Comment: Sets cannot contain duplicate elements, so the concept of determining when something is a superset under these conditions doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The last example should be `true`, for two reasons: (1) repetition doesn't matter in sets: `{1,1} = {1}`. (2) A set is its own subset and superset; if the two aren't supposed to be equal, they're called "proper subset" and "proper superset".

Comment: @AdamRackis sorry I don't mean superset then, what is a better term?

Comment: "Bag" is sometimes used to refer to unordered collections that allow for repetition.

Comment: @Harry - I think my edit accomplishes this

Comment: @Harry: if "bag" is the better term, please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: Check out my answer. Also the performance test cases http://jsperf.com/js-compare-set

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One option is to sort the two arrays, then traverse both, comparing elements. If an element in the sub-bag candidate is not found in the super-bag, the former is not a sub-bag. Sorting is generally O(n*log(n)) and the comparison is O(max(s,t)), where *s* and *t* are the array sizes, for a total time complexity of O(m*log(m)), where m=max(s,t).

```
function superbag(sup, sub) {
    sup.sort();
    sub.sort();
    var i, j;
    for (i=0,j=0; i<sup.length && j<sub.length;) {
        if (sup[i] < sub[j]) {
            ++i;
        } else if (sup[i] == sub[j]) {
            ++i; ++j;
        } else {
            // sub[j] not in sup, so sub not subbag
            return false;
        }
    }
    // make sure there are no elements left in sub
    return j == sub.length;
}
```

If the elements in the actual code are integers, you can use a special-purpose integer sorting algorithm (such as [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)) for an overall O(max(s,t)) time complexity, though if the bags are small, the built-in `Array.sort` will likely run faster than a custom integer sort.

A solution with potentially lesser time-complexity is to create a bag type. Integer bags are particularly easy. Flip the existing arrays for the bags: create an object or an array with the integers as keys and a repeat count for values. Using an array won't waste space by creating as [arrays are sparse in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510778/are-javascript-arrays-sparse). You can use bag operations for sub-bag or super-bag checks.  For example, subtract the super from the sub candidate and test if the result non-empty. Alternatively, the `contains` operation should be O(1) (or possibly O(log(n))), so looping over the sub-bag candidate and testing if the super-bag containment exceeds the sub-bag's containment for each sub-bag element should be O(n) or O(n*log(n)).

The following is untested. Implementation of `isInt` left as an exercise.

```
function IntBag(from) {
    if (from instanceof IntBag) {
        return from.clone();
    } else if (from instanceof Array) {
        for (var i=0; i < from.length) {
            this.add(from[i]);
        }
    } else if (from) {
        for (p in from) {
            /* don't test from.hasOwnProperty(p); all that matters
               is that p and from[p] are ints
             */
            if (isInt(p) && isInt(from[p])) {
                this.add(p, from[p]);
            }
        }
    }
}
IntBag.prototype=[];
IntBag.prototype.size=0;
IntBag.prototype.clone = function() {
    var clone = new IntBag();
    this.each(function(i, count) {
        clone.add(i, count);
    });
    return clone;
};
IntBag.prototype.contains = function(i) {
    if (i in this) {
        return this[i];
    }
    return 0;
};
IntBag.prototype.add = function(i, count) {
    if (!count) {
        count = 1;
    }
    if (i in this) {
        this[i] += count;
    } else {
        this[i] = count;
    }
    this.size += count;
};
IntBag.prototype.remove = function(i, count) {
    if (! i in this) {
        return;
    }
    if (!count) {
        count = 1;
    }
    this[i] -= count;
    if (this[i] > 0) {
        // element is still in bag
        this.size -= count;
    } else {
        // remove element entirely
        this.size -= count + this[i];
        delete this[i];
    }
};
IntBag.prototype.each = function(f) {
    var i;
    foreach (i in this) {
        f(i, this[i]);
    }
};
IntBag.prototype.find = function(p) {
    var result = [];
    var i;
    foreach (i in this.elements) {
        if (p(i, this[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
IntBag.prototype.sub = function(other) {
    other.each(function(i, count) {
        this.remove(i, count);
    });
    return this;
};
IntBag.prototype.union = function(other) {
    var union = this.clone();
    other.each(function(i, count) {
        if (union.contains(i) < count) {
            union.add(i, count - union.contains(i));
        }
    });
    return union;
};
IntBag.prototype.intersect = function(other) {
    var intersection = new IntBag();
    this.each(function (i, count) {
        if (other.contains(i)) {
            intersection.add(i, Math.min(count, other.contains(i)));
        }
    });
    return intersection;
};
IntBag.prototype.diff = function(other) {
    var mine = this.clone();
    mine.sub(other);
    var others = other.clone();
    others.sub(this);
    mine.union(others);
    return mine;
};
IntBag.prototype.subbag = function(super) {
    return this.size <= super.size
       && null !== this.find(
           function (i, count) {
               return super.contains(i) < this.contains(i);
           }));
};
```

See also "[comparing javascript arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549225/90527)" for an example implementation of a set of objects, should you ever wish to disallow repetition of elements.

Comment: 'is left as an exercise' = 'I can't be bothered' :)

Comment: @derekdreery: don't think attacking my pride will make me give the answer to the homework I assigned; I'm wise to your tricks ;)

Answer (score 35):

Do you have to support crummy browsers?  If not, the [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function should make this easy.

If arr1 is a superset of arr2, then each member in arr2 must be present in arr1

```
var isSuperset = arr2.every(function(val) { return arr1.indexOf(val) >= 0; });
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWV5A/2/)

**EDIT**

So you're defining superset such that for each element in arr2, it occurs in arr1 the same number of times?  I think [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will help you do that (grab the shim from the preceding MDN link to support older browsers):

```
var isSuperset = arr2.every(function (val) { 
    var numIn1 = arr1.filter(function(el) { return el === val;  }).length;
    var numIn2 = arr2.filter(function(el) { return el === val;  }).length;
    return numIn1 === numIn2;   
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWV5A/3/)

**END EDIT**

---

If you do want to support older browsers, the MDN link above has a shim you can add, which I reproduce here for your convenience:

```
if (!Array.prototype.every)  
{  
  Array.prototype.every = function(fun /*, thisp */)  
  {  
    "use strict";  

    if (this == null)  
      throw new TypeError();  

    var t = Object(this);  
    var len = t.length >>> 0;  
    if (typeof fun != "function")  
      throw new TypeError();  

    var thisp = arguments[1];  
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)  
    {  
      if (i in t && !fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t))  
        return false;  
    }  

    return true;  
  };  
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that this will be an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, so avoid running it on large arrays.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar - yes, yes it is.  I'll add an edit to my answer warning OP about using this with large inputs

Comment: Thanks Adam i edited my question a little bit, I need to check for multiples of the same members as well. re the last example. Thanks

Comment: @amnotiam - but just to be clear, I really was interested in seeing if you had any tricks to more slickly solve this; I wasn't fishing for votes

Comment: @AdamRackis - Sure thing. ;) BTW, if you wanted to eek out a little more performance from the solution that tests for dupes as well, you could maintain a table of dupe values to avoid repeating the same test on the second pass. Probably not worth if we're just dealing with small arrays though.

Comment: I know you weren't fishing... or do I?... ;)

Comment: @amnotiam - ;) (I have to add in cruft like this since your new user name is too short!)

Comment: in ES6 : `arr2.every((i) => arr1.indexOf(i) != -1 )`

Comment: @vsync - for sure.  I'm sure lots and lots of my old answers could benefit from some ES6 :)

Comment: @AdamRackis - as of everyone's ;)

Comment: Clean one line ES6 version of the first example here: https://jsfiddle.net/martinkrulltott/n4orwajs/

Answer (score 5):

No one has posted a recursive function yet and those are always fun. Call it like `arr1.containsArray( arr2 )`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/X9jed/

```js
Array.prototype.containsArray = function ( array /*, index, last*/ ) {

    if( arguments[1] ) {
        var index = arguments[1], last = arguments[2];
    } else {
        var index = 0, last = 0; this.sort(); array.sort();
    };

    return index == array.length
        || ( last = this.indexOf( array[index], last ) ) > -1
        && this.containsArray( array, ++index, ++last );

};
```

Answer (score 4):

Using objects (read: hash tables) in stead of sorting should reduce the amortized complexity to O(m+n):

```
function bagContains(arr1, arr2) {
    var o = {}
    var result = true;

    // Count all the objects in container
    for(var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if(!o[arr1[i]]) {
            o[arr1[i]] = 0;
        }
        o[arr1[i]]++;
    }

    // Subtract all the objects in containee
    // And exit early if possible
    for(var i=0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if(!o[arr2[i]]) {
            o[arr2[i]] = 0;
        }
        if(--o[arr2[i]] < 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(bagContains([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3]));
console.log(bagContains([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 3]));
console.log(bagContains([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 7]));
```

Which yields `true`, `false`, `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Found this on [github lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1743) library. This function use built in functions to solve the problem. `.includes()` , `.indexOf()` and `.every()`

```js
var array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var array2 = ['B', 'C', 'E'];
var array3 = ['B', 'C', 'Z'];
var array4 = [];

function arrayContainsArray (superset, subset) {
  if (0 === subset.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return subset.every(function (value) {
    return (superset.includes(value));
  });
}

 function arrayContainsArray1 (superset, subset) {
   if (0 === subset.length) {
     return false;
   }
   return subset.every(function (value) {
     return (superset.indexOf(value) >= 0);
   });
}

console.log(arrayContainsArray(array1,array2)); //true
console.log(arrayContainsArray(array1,array3)); //false
console.log(arrayContainsArray(array1,array4)); //false

console.log(arrayContainsArray1(array1,array2)); //true
console.log(arrayContainsArray1(array1,array3)); //false
console.log(arrayContainsArray1(array1,array4)); //false
```

Answer (score 2):

If arr2 is subset of arr1, then `Length of set(arr1 + arr2) == Length of set(arr1)`

```
var arr1 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

Array.from(new Set(arr1)).length == Array.from(new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))).length
```

Comment: This doesn't account for duplicates. Also, you hurt time complexity by converting it to an array. `Set`s have a `size` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
Array.prototype.containsIds = function (arr_ids) {
    var status = true;
    var current_arr = this;
    arr_ids.forEach(function(id) {
        if(!current_arr.includes(parseInt(id))){
            status = false;
            return false; // exit forEach
        }
    });
    return status;
};

// Examples
[1,2,3].containsIds([1]); // true
[1,2,3].containsIds([2,3]); // true
[1,2,3].containsIds([3,4]); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

As for another approach you may do as follows;

```js
function checkIn(a,b){
  return b.every(function(e){
                   return e === this.splice(this.indexOf(e),1)[0];
                 }, a.slice()); // a.slice() is the "this" in the every method
}

var arr1  = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    arr2  = [1, 2],
    arr3  = [1,2,3,3];
console.log(checkIn(arr1,arr2));
console.log(checkIn(arr1,arr3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick solution here take two arrays if `b` is longer than it can't be a super set so return false.  Then loop through `b` to see if a contains the element.  If so delete it from `a` and move on if not return false.  Worse case scenario is if `b` is a subset then time will `b.length`.

```
function isSuper(a,b){
  var l=b.length,i=0,c;
  if(l>a.length){return false}
  else{
    for(i;i<l;i++){
      c=a.indexOf(b[i]);
      if(c>-1){
        a.splice(c,1);
      }
      else{return false}
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This assumes that inputs will not always be in order and if `a` is `1,2,3` and `b` is `3,2,1` it will still return true.

Answer (score -1):

Yet another simple solution is the following:

```
let a = [1,2,'a',3,'b',4,5]

let b = [1,2,4]

console.log(b.every((i) => a.includes(i)))
```

Hope it helps