# Compare two arrays and return unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have the two following arrays:

```
array1 = [{'itemCode':'a'}, {'itemCode':'b'}, {'itemCode':'c'}]; 
array2 = [{'itemCode':'a'}, {'itemCode':'b'}, {'itemCode':'d'}];
```

I'm looking for a way to slice array2 from array 1 and return the "F" value.

Does anyone know of a quick way to do this in JavaScript, Im totally stumped.

I tried _difference and _unique from underscore, but that doesnt seem to be the right solution.

```
var diffArray = _.difference(array1, array2);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see "F value" in your arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147278/using-underscores-difference-method-on-objects

Answer (score 0):

[Get the unique values from two arrays and put them in another array - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912538/get-the-unique-values-from-two-arrays-and-put-them-in-another-array-jquery)
I think this will answer your question

```
var unique = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    var found = false;
    for(var j = 0; array2.length; j++){
     if(array1[i].itemCode == array2[j].itemCode){
      found = true;
      break; 
    }
   }
   if(found == false){
   unique.push(array1[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `indexOf()` will work when the elements are objects like this. It doesn't compare objects recursively.

Comment: Yes you are right, i overlooked the datatype. But it sort of demonstrate how its done. I am not familiar with javascript

Comment: It doesn't really demonstrate how it's done, because you have to do something completely different when `indexOf()` can't match them.