# Compare 2 arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: jquery

I am trying to compare 2 arrays using jquery and remove duplicates from that.

This is my code.Is this logic correct?

```
var list1 = [6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var list2 = [2, 4, 6, 5, 1, 9, 8, 7, 8];

var newArray = [];
var index1, index2;
$.each(list1, function(i, value)) {
  index1 = $.inArray(list1[i]);
  index2 = $.inArray(newArray[i]);
  if (index2 == -1) {
    newArray.push(list2[i]);
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
[3,5,9,8]
```

Comment: You never do anything with `index1`.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes correct.

Comment: The `i`  belongs to `list1`, but you use it with `list2`, so your code would fail if  `list1` contains more elements then `list2`.

Comment: @t.niese so I should not use [i] right?

Comment: @krish is it necessary to use jquery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: @RahulSingh yes.

Comment: vanila javascript wont work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the unique values from two arrays and put them in another array - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912538/get-the-unique-values-from-two-arrays-and-put-them-in-another-array-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr1=[6,7,3,4,1,2];
    var arr2=[2,4,6,5,1,9,8,7,8];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var newArray=$.merge($(arr1).not(arr2).get(),$(arr2).not(arr1).get());
        console.log(newArray);
    });
</script>
```

It give out put as

```
[ 3, 5, 9, 8,8 ]
```

**Another answer with**  using $.each,$.inArray and .push only
Try this

```
var list1 = [6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var list2 = [2, 4, 6, 5, 1, 9, 8, 7, 8];

var newArray = [];
$.each(list1, function(i, value){
    if($.inArray(value,list2)==-1){
        newArray.push(value);
    }
});
$.each(list2, function(i, value){
    if($.inArray(value,list1)==-1){
        newArray.push(value);
    }
});
newArray=$.unique(newArray);
console.log(newArray);
```

It give out put as

```
[ 3, 5, 9, 8]
```

Comment: Please give me suggestion for this question using `$.each`,`$.inArray` and `.push`.

Comment: @krish try the second answer.

Comment: here we are passing `list1`  in $.each but why we are checking with `list2` ?

Comment: We are chacking the value of  `list1` is present in `list2` array or not .

Comment: Instead of `$.unique` can we check like this `if($.inArray(value,list2)==-1 && $.inArray(list2,newArray==-1))` ??

Comment: `$.unique` is used to remove duplicate values in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Concat the arrays and filter the two:

```js
var list1=[6,7,3,4,1,2];
var list2=[2,4,6,5,1,9,8,7,8];

function removeDuplicates(arr1, arr2) {
    return [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2).filter(e => ! (arr2.includes(e) && arr1.includes(e))))];
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(list1, list2));
```

Comment: Please give me suggestion for this question using `$.each`,`$.inArray` and `.push`.please.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way similar to yours...

```
var list1=[6,7,3,4,1,2];
var list2=[2,4,6,5,1,9,8,7,8]; 
var list = list1.concat(list2);
var uniqueList = []; 
$.each(list , function(i, el){
  if($.inArray(el, uniqueList) === -1) 
   {
    uniqueList .push(el);
   }
});
```

Comment: It wont produce `[3,5,9,8]` as result.

Comment: Then what it will produce?what is the list here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/10778/)

```
var list1 = [6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 2];
var list2 = [2, 4, 6, 5, 1, 9, 8, 7, 8];
var newArray = [];
$.each(list1, function(i, value) {
  if ($.inArray(value, list2) == -1) {
    newArray.push(value);
  }
});
$.each(list2, function(i, value) {
  if ($.inArray(value, list1) == -1) {
    newArray.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Used $.each,$.inArray and .push as requested