# Check if one array is contained in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to know if this array is contained in this array:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I know I can do 2 for loops and check item per item, but is there a oneliner for it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if the values of array 1 are in array 2? Or if th whole array (including `[]`) is in it?

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc

Comment: @Alan I mean the values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array

Comment: If the array elements are simple strings as shown in your example, you can do `contains = (y.sort().join('').indexOf(x.sort().join('')) !== -1);` - where x is the smaller array (needed) and y is the larger one (haystack).

Comment: @doniyor What do you want return? Just true or false?

Comment: @Alan yes, just true or false, but only if the whole needle is found in haystack

Comment: @doniyor Say a, b are in it, but not c would you want to return false or true for the ones that are and flase for the ones that ren't?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using `Array.prototype.some`.  This will run the provided function against all the items in an array, and return true if the function returns true for any of them.  The following will return true if any items from `array` are not contained in `otherArray`, which you can use to determine if one array is fully contained in the other:

```
return !array.some(function(item) {
   return otherArray.indexOf(item) === -1;
});
```

However, this is not the most elegant solution.  The logic can be summed up as:

> not any items from array not in other array

Which has far too many negatives.  We can instead use `Array.prototype.every`, which is very similar except it returns true only if all items in an array return true for the provided function.  The below is equivalent to what we had before:

```
return array.every(function(item) {
   return otherArray.indexOf(item) !== -1;
});
```

Except that can be summed up as:

> all items in array in other array

Finally, we can implement this as an additional prototype function.  Note that the second parameter for `every` is optional, and sets what `this` refers to in the function when provided.  If we did not pass it in, we would not be able to refer to the `this` from the outside scope.

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(array) {
    return array.every(function(item) {
        return this.indexOf(item) !== -1;
    }, this);
}
```

This can now be used as a one liner in our code:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].contains(['a', 'b']) // returns true
```

If you are able to use ECMAScipt 6, you can use arrow functions to make this a true one-liner.

```
return array.every(item => otherArray.indexOf(item) !== -1);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.some` and `Array.prototype.every` are part of ECMAScript 5, which is supported in most modern browsers, including mobile browsers. Worth noting it's not supported in IE8 or earlier. http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5

Answer (score 8):

## ES6 one-lined answer

```
containedArray.every(element => mainArray.includes(element))
```

...an improved answer on top of the ES6 suggestion of @James Brierley:
by using [every(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (which returns `true` if all the elements pass the test we've provided - `false` otherwise) alongside `includes`, which IMO is more human-readable - and less error prone - than checking for a `index !== -1`.

```
var mainArray = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

var containedArray = [1, 30, 39, 29]

console.log(containedArray.every(element => mainArray.includes(element)));
```