# How do I correctly use indexOf() with several elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array of

```
var clickedImages = Session.get('clickedImages'); 
clickedImages = clickedImages.map( function(a) {return a.imageId;});

console.log("clickedImages Ids are: " ,...clickedImages);
```

Which yields:

**clickedImages Ids are:  TaTg6hf3Gok5NsWYp XzGxS3LDtJ4DrXSdc 8CdapJoeSxSScHKFs**

```
var TotalOfallImageIds =  buyList.find().fetch().map(function(u) { return u._id; });
console.log(TotalOfallIds);
```

Which yields:

```
["yzML7ZLvkWkjBBvq5", "XzGxS3LDtJ4DrXSdc", "TaTg6hf3Gok5NsWYp", "8CdapJoeSxSScHKFs"]
```

However when I run the code below, why do I get a false?

```
(TotalOfallImageIds.indexOf(clickedImages) > -1);
```

The code above yields: **false**

How do I correctly use indexOf() with several elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if every element in one array is in a second array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array)

Comment: Loop over the clicked images and call `indexOf` with each of them.

Comment: What do you want `TotalOfallImageIds.indexOf(clickedImages)` to do? Specifically, what is it meant to check for?

Comment: Do you want to return true when each of the clicked image is are in the list of total image ids, or when at least one appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.indexOf is for comparing an item, so instead you need to iterate over one array and indexOf with the other

```
var allClicked = true;

for (var i = 0; i < clickedImages.length; i++) {
    var clickedImg = clickedImages[i];
    allClicked = TotalOfallImageIds.indexOf(clickedImg) > -1 && allClicked;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no entry in `TotalOfallImageIds` that is `===` the **array** of clicked image IDs referenced by `clickedImages`. No array is ever `===` to a string (because the result of `===` is always `false` when the operands are not the same type). `indexOf` uses `===` for comparisons.