# Javascript How to identify if all elements of one array are present in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexof

I need to create a function to check if all the letters in the second string of a two string array are present in the first string. The function I wrote seems to work for most of the examples I tried with it but ["hello" , "hey"] returns true despite there not being a y in hello and I don't understand why.

Here's my code:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  arr[0] =arr[0].toUpperCase().split("");
  arr[1] =arr[1].toUpperCase().split("");

  for(i=0;i<arr[1].length;i++){
    if(arr[0].indexOf(arr[1][i])>=0){
      return true;
} else {return false;}}}

mutation(["hello", "Hey"]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if every element in one array is in a second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning true even if one character is matched ,Try below code it checks if all characters are present or not

```
    function mutation(arr) {
    arr[0] = arr[0].toUpperCase().split("");
    arr[1] = arr[1].toUpperCase().split("");
    var count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++) {
        if (arr[0].indexOf(arr[1][i]) >= 0) {
            count++;
        }

    }

    return count === arr[1].length

}

mutation(["hello", "Hey"]);
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please *explain* what the solution you're showing does, and *why/how* that code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

here is one more efficient solution, it works only for lowercase letters.

```js
(function(){

    function charCode(str, i){
        return str.charCodeAt(i) - 97;
    }

    function isMutation(a,b){
        const aArr = new Uint8Array(26);
        const bArr = new Uint8Array(26);
    
        let i=0;
        let index = 0;
        while(i<a.length){
            ++aArr[charCode(a, i)];
            ++i;
        }

        i = 0;
        while(i<b.length){

            ++bArr[charCode(b, i)];
            ++i;
        }

        i = 0;
        while(i < 26){
            if(!(aArr[i]===0 && bArr[i]===0 || aArr[i]>0 && bArr[i]>0)){
                return false
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return true;
    }

    console.assert(isMutation('hello', 'oleh') === true);
    console.assert(isMutation('hello', 'hey') === false);

})();
```

you can also compare sum of uniq chars in the both arrays, but in this case you have to add each letters only once.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of the code solutions suggested by user georg at [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array).

For example, the function below could be used to sort each array `(arr[0] and arr[1])` and remove duplicates.

Credit to user georg at the link above.

```
function uniq(a) {
    return a.sort().filter(function(item, pos, ary) {
        return !pos || item != ary[pos - 1];
    })
}
```

Once you have sorted/removed duplicates, you can test to see if the two returned strings are equal or not.

Hello => EHLO, and Hey => EHY

EHLO !== EHY