# How to check if a list is a sublist of another list with order?

Tags: javascript

If I have a list `l1=["A","B","C"]`, and I have another list `l2=["X","Y","Z","A","B","C","1","2","3"]`, how can I efficiently check if `l1` appears in `l2`, with order as well.

In this case it does appear in the list, but instead if `l1` was `["A","C","B"]`, then it would not. Or if it was `l2=["X","Y","Z","A","D","B", "C","1","2","3"]` this should also not be found as it has to be sequential too.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if every element in one array is in a second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array)

Comment: It should be based on order and be sequential too.

Comment: idk maybe I'm just feeling extra lazy, but I'd probably just make the array a string by joining them with ".*" and then passing that to a regex object and testing that regex against the string form of l2

Comment: But is that efficient?

Comment: probably not, but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function check(l1, l2) {
 return !!~l2.join('').indexOf(l1.join(''))
}
console.log(check(["A","B","C"], ["X","Y","Z","A","B","C","1","2","3"]));
console.log(check(["A","B","C"], ["X","Y","Z","A","D","B", "C","1","2","3"]));
```

**Update**

Here it how this is works:

`l1.join('')` and `l2.join('')` is convert the *array* to a *string* [join on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

`.indexOf` part tell us where is the poison of the `l2` string in the `l1` [indexOf on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

`~` trick is a Bitwise NOT operator without going into the details, it is convert `-1` to `0` and `0` to `-1` in Java-Script every number is `true` except `0`

`!!` (Double negation) is convert `Number` type to `Boolean` type [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Whats the `!!~` ?

Comment: For my own enrichment, could you explain what your code is doing? Especially that tilde...

Comment: Wouldn't the two nots cancel out?

Comment: `~` is the binary NOT operator, this is a codegolf solution. Peter, please explain what is going on here for those not used to dissecting unreadable code?

Comment: And is this really an efficient  solution? What if the array had millions of items?

Comment: @omega if the array gets into sizes that big, consider using a Set instead. Much faster!

Comment: @Sterling Archer  `~` with `indexOf` is really useful  because convert `-1` to `0` and `0` to `-1` (and other numbers too but it is not important here), because of that we know it is found or not, (but not the position)

`!!` is for convert numbers to Boolean, if you don't like it you can use: `return (l2.join('').indexOf(l1.join('')) !== -1)`

Comment: But a set doesn't care about ordering? But also a set is newer js syntax, I am limited by making it work on IE10.

Comment: @omega It does care about the order because it turns both arrays into strings and then checks if the first string exists (as is) inside the second string. And it appears to work in IE10.

Comment: You should use `join(',')`. With `.join('')` you'll consider `["a", "bc"]` equal to `["ab", "c"]`.

Comment: But even with comma, you'll consider `["a,b"]` equal to `["a", "b"]`.

Comment: there is a lots of things what can improve on this code example: check 1st array is bigger than 2nd one, check both parameter is an array etc..., I just come up with this answer based on the specification in the question.

Comment: Peter, please take the time to explain your code, what it does and *how*; while it's a beautifully concise answer (albeit with imperfections) there's no simple means for the OP, or future users, to understand what's going on or learning from your answer, which is the whole point of the Q&A format.

Comment: @DavidThomas I updated my answer. English is not my 1st language, but i try to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `every()` method and store index of first element if found in second array and then just increment that index and check if it exists in second array.

```js
var l1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
var l2 = ["X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "1", "2", "3"]

var check = l1.every(function(e, i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    var start = l2.indexOf(e);
    if (start == -1) return false;
    else {
      this.start = start;
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    return e == l2[this.start += 1]
  }
}, {});

console.log(check)
```

Update: You can also use `every()` and `some()`.

```js
var l1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
var l2 = ["X", "A", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "1", "2", "3"]

function check(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.some(function(e, i) {
    if (e == arr1[0]) {
      return arr1.every((a, j) => a == arr2[i + j])
    }
  })
}


console.log(check(l1, l2))
```

Comment: Does this check for ordering and sequantialness?

Comment: `return this.start = start` should be `this.start = start`; return true`. And `!start` should be `start == -1`.

Comment: The problem in both cases is that `indexOf` returns `0` when it finds the match at the beginning of the array, and `0` is falsey.

Comment: Another case that fails: if the first element of `l1` is repeated in `l2`: `l2 = [""X", "A", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "1", "2", "3"]` because `indexOf(e)` will only find the first occurrence.

Comment: @Barmar Could you take a look at update and let me know what you think.

Comment: Better, and simpler, too. No special case like `if (i == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, and it seems to work fine. Does anyone see any issues?

```
        var l1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
        var l2 = ["X", "Y", "Z", "a", "B", "C", "1", "2", "3"]


        console.log(search(l1,l2,0));


        function CIindexOf(lst, val, offset) {
            var lVal = val.toLowerCase();
            for(var i=offset; i<lst.length; i++) {
                if (lst[i].toLowerCase() == lVal) return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        function search(l1, l2, offset) {
            if (l1.length == 0) return 0;
            var index = CIindexOf(l2, l1[0], offset);
            if (index == -1) return -1;
            for (var i=1; i<l1.length; i++) {
                if (l1[i].toLowerCase() != l2[index+i].toLowerCase()) return search(l1, l2, index+1);
            }
            return index;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This version has a good performance (no callbacks in methods), and work with any type of content.

```js
function isContain(arr1, arr2) {
 var arr2Length = arr2.length;
 if (arr2Length > arr1.length) return false; // quick check if arr2 is bigger than arr1 is always false
 var lastPos = -1;
 var i;
 while (~(lastPos = arr1.indexOf(arr2[0], lastPos + 1))) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr2Length; i++) {
   if (arr1[lastPos + i] !== arr2[i]) break;
  }
  if (i === arr2Length ) return true;
 }
 return false;
}

console.log(isContain(["X","Y","Z","A","B","C","1","2","3"], ["A","B","C"]));
console.log(isContain(["X","Y","Z","A","D","B", "C","1","2","3"], ["A","B","C"]));
console.log(isContain(["X","Y","Z","A","B","C","1","2","3"], ["AB","C"]));
console.log(isContain(["X","Y","Z","AB","C","1","2","3"], ["AB","C"]));
console.log(isContain([false, false, true, false, false, true], [true, true]));
console.log(isContain([false, false, true, false, false, true], [true, false]));
console.log(isContain([false, false, true, false, false, true], [1, 0]));
console.log(isContain([1, 1], [1, 1, 1]));
```