# How to check if objects are in an array based on a value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, how do I check if ALL the objects in `array2` exist in `array1` based on their `id`?

```
const array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
const array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]
```

For some reason, I couldn't find the solution on Google.

I thought about this:

```
const result = array1.every(obj1 => {
  // what do use here? includes? contains?
})

console.log(result)
```

But I'm kind of stuck in the middle of the code. The most logical solution to me was to use `includes`. However, `includes` doesn't seem to take a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes. So I'm not sure if I can check the objects by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in combination with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const result = array2.every(o2 => array1.some(o1 => o1.id === o2.id));
```

This will check if every element in `array2` has a matching element in `array1`.

---

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
const array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
const array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

const result = array2.every(o2 => array1.some(o1 => o1.id === o2.id));

console.log(result);
```

If `array1` is large, or used repeatedly to perform this operation, the `Set`-based approach proposed in other answers is more optimized.

Answer (score 4):

`includes` will only be true if both objects are the same reference in memory, which is (probably) not the case. Instead, I'd create a `Set` of `array1`'s `id`s initially, and then check to see if every `array2` `id` is in the set. This way, you only have to iterate over `array1` once, at the very beginning (`Set`s have `O(1)` lookup time):

```js
const array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
const array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

const idSet = new Set(array1.map(({ id }) => id));
console.log(
  array2.every(({ id }) => idSet.has(id))
);
```

(Arrays do not have a `contains` function)

Answer (score 3):

```
var matching = [];

for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if (array2[i].id === array1[j].id) {
            matching.push(array2[i].id);       
        }
    }
}

if (array2.length === matching.length) {
    console.log("All elements exist");
} else {
    console.log("One or more of the elements does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar type of question is already asked. You can refer that also on this link
[Check if every element in one array is in a second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628059/check-if-every-element-in-one-array-is-in-a-second-array)

```js
const array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
const array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

let array1ids = array1.map(a => a.id);
const result = array2.every(a => array1ids.includes(a.id));
console.log(result);

const array3 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
const array4 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 6 }];

let array3ids = array3.map(a => a.id);
const result2 = array4.every(a => array3ids.includes(a.id));
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays, I recommend pre-processing the array that's used as the criteria to create a `Set` so that each check is an O(1) lookup and overall O(n) instead of O(n^2). This code makes a couple assumptions though, namely:

- The criteria is based on a `select()` function of the `object`, its `index` in the array, and a reference to the `array`.
- The selection used as the criteria returns a primitive and can perform an equality check identical to a `Set` using `a === b || (a !== a && b !== b)` (to deal with `a` and `b` being `NaN`)

```js
const has = select => array => {
  const set = new Set(array.map(select))
  return (object, index, array) => set.has(select(object, index, array))
}

const hasId = has(({ id }) => id)
const array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
const array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]

const result1 = array1.every(hasId(array2))
const result2 = array2.every(hasId(array1))

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```