# Extending Object prototype by adding a function in a "namespace"

Tags: javascript, prototype

The below code (also in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bEQAISInQcNI9C8rIcpR)) is adapted from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997811/274677).
I am trying to implement the same logic, only add the `uniqueId` function in a special property of the `Object.prototype` to keep things clear.

The below code works when run using `nodejs` (also the HTML-ized Plunker example works as well). I.e. the console prints three unique object identifiers: `0`, `1` and `2`.

However, when the `test` switch variable is set to 1, console prints `0`, `0` and `0`.

What should I do to add the `uniqueId` function in the `foo` namespace?

```
function addUniqueId1(){
    if (Object.prototype.foo===undefined) {
        Object.prototype.foo = {};
        console.log('foo "namespace" added');
    }
    if (Object.prototype.foo.uniqueId===undefined) {
        var i = 0;
        Object.prototype.foo.uniqueId = function() {
            console.log('uniqueId function called');
            if (this.___uniqueId === undefined) {
                this.___uniqueId = i++;
            }
            return this.___uniqueId;
        };
        console.log('function defined');
    }
}


function addUniqueId2() {
    if (Object.prototype.uniqueId === undefined) {
        var i = 0;
        Object.prototype.uniqueId = function() {
            if (this.___uniqueId === undefined) {
                this.___uniqueId = i++;
            }
            return this.___uniqueId;
        };
    };
};


var test=2; // if you set this to 1 it stops working

if (test==1)
    addUniqueId1();
else
    addUniqueId2();

var xs = [{}, {}, {}];
for (var i = 0 ; i < xs.length ; i++) {
    if (test==1)
        console.log('object id is: ['+xs[i].foo.uniqueId()+']');
    else
        console.log('object id is: ['+xs[i].uniqueId()+']');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `foo` with a getter, to allow it to access `this` for use within the hash of sub-method(s):

```
function defineFoo() {
  if (Object.prototype.foo) return;

  var i = 0;

  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function() {
      var self = this;
      return {
        uniqueId: function() { 
          return self.__uniqueId = self.uniqueId || ++i;
        }
      };
    }
  });

}
```

Now

```
defineFoo();
obj.foo.uniqueId()
```

If you prefer, an alternative to using `self`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'foo', {
  get: function() {
    return {
      uniqueId: function() { 
         return this.__uniqueId = this.uniqueId || ++i;
      }.bind(this)
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: where should the "counter" variable (`var i = 0` in my example) be declared and initialized so that `uniqueId` gets a closure over it?