# Get object identifier of an object in Node.js

Tags: node.js

In Ruby we can call `#__id__` or `#object_id` to get the [unique object identifier](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__) of any object.

What is the equivalent in Node.js?

*Specifically, I am looking to log this identifier to debug an application and see if one or many objects are being created.*

Comment: I don't think JS has built in anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Standard ECMAScript does not expose any interfaces that return unique object identifiers, and there does not seem to be any API specific to Node.js either.  You can, however, assign unique IDs yourself using `WeakMap`:

```js
const objectId = (() => {
  'use strict';

  const objIdMap = new WeakMap;
  let counter = 0n;

  return obj => {
    let ident = objIdMap.get(obj);
    if (ident === void 0) {
      ident = counter++;
      objIdMap.set(obj, ident);
    }
    return ident;
  };
})();

{
  const o = {};
  const op = new Proxy(o, {});

  console.log(
    `an object is #${objectId(o)}`);
  console.log(
    `a proxy is #${objectId(op)}`);

  const oc = { ...o };

  console.log(
    `an object copy is #${objectId(oc)}`);
}

{
  const o = Object.freeze({});

  console.log(
    `a frozen object is #${objectId(o)}`);
  console.log(
    `the same frozen object is #${objectId(o)}`);
}

document.body.dataset.a = 123;
console.log(
  `document.body.dataset is #${objectId(document.body.dataset)}`);
console.log(`dataset contains`, document.body.dataset);

console.log(
  `Object.prototype is #${objectId(Object.prototype)}`);
console.log(
  `a fresh object is #${objectId({})}`);
console.log(
  `another fresh object is #${objectId({})}`);
```

This will assign consecutive integers to objects as they are encountered.  In engines that implement the [Symbols as WeakMap keys proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-symbols-as-weakmap-keys), it will also assign identifiers to symbols, which you may or may not want: use the `typeof` operator as appropriate if you want to filter them out.  (If you *do* want to assign identifiers to symbols even in engines that do not implement the proposal, you can fall back to `Map`, but beware that the symbols will be effectively leaked.  Use it as a transient debugging aid only.)

If you want to get really fancy, you can employ [`FinalizationRegistry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) to recycle IDs of objects that have been garbage-collected.  I would recommend against this, though, as it may end up confusing if you end up obtaining IDs of some objects, have the objects collected, then the IDs reassigned, and mistake the zombie IDs as referring to the new objects.

Elsewhere you may encounter other solutions: parasitic properties, whether string or symbol-keyed, will not work on non-extensible objects, may mutate the state of the object observable elsewhere, will fail to distinguish proxies from their targets, and often obtaining the ID of `Object.prototype` suffices to break the system entirely.  Avoid these.  See below why:

```js
// DO NOT USE this implementation or anything like it
const BAD_objectId = (() => {
  'use strict';

  // const objIdKey = Symbol(); would have been only marginally better
  const objIdKey = '__OBJECT_ID_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED';
  let counter = 0n;

  return obj => {
    let ident = obj[objIdKey];
    if (ident === void 0) {
      ident = counter++;
      obj[objIdKey] = ident;
    }
    return ident;
  };
})();

{
  const o = {};
  const op = new Proxy(o, {});

  console.log(
    `an object is #${BAD_objectId(o)}`);
  console.log(
    `a proxy is also #${BAD_objectId(op)}`);

  const oc = { ...o };

  console.log(
    `an object copy is also #${BAD_objectId(oc)}`);
}

try {
  const o = Object.freeze({});

  console.log(
    `a frozen object is #${BAD_objectId(o)}`);
  console.log(
    `the same frozen object is #${BAD_objectId(o)}`);
} catch (e) {
  console.warn(`${e}`);
}

document.body.dataset.a = 123;
console.log(
  `document.body.dataset is #${BAD_objectId(document.body.dataset)}`);
console.log(`dataset contains`, document.body.dataset);

console.log(
  `Object.prototype is #${BAD_objectId(Object.prototype)}`);
console.log(
  `a fresh object is also #${BAD_objectId({})}`);
console.log(
  `another fresh object is also #${BAD_objectId({})}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing like this built-in, but you can use a `Map` indexed by object to check this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

```js
const m = new Map();

// then for each object
if (m.has(object)) {
  console.log('already seen this', m.get(object), 'times');
  m.set(object, m.get(object) + 1);
} else {
  m.set(object, 1);
}
```