# For recent days, Is it ok to append properties directly to DOM element

Tags: javascript

I am building a library recently and I am extending the DOM element returned by document.querySelector directly. The good part is I did not extend the prototype of Element, I only extend the specific element returned by document.querySelector.

I understand it is not right earlier years especially for IE. so I do want to know if it is ok or good(not effect performance and not mess up prototypes) for modern browsers now days.

Best Regards,
Hao

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915341/whats-wrong-with-adding-properties-to-dom-element-objects

Comment: Try to be more specific, describe what you're doing, say why you think it may not be right and why it may be, etc... Otherwise, this will probably close as "primarily opinion-based".